# Git Update Hook: Finding all files being pushed to a new branch

Tags: git, hook

I am trying to enforce some coding style in my team. So I've written a git update hook, that checks all the files being pushed.

However, it works perfectly for the branches existing on the remote, but it doesn't work correctly for new branches.

To get the list of files on an existing branch, I use `git diff --name-status --diff-filter=AM oldrev newrev`, where oldrev and newrev are the SHA1's I get as arguments.

Using this same line for *new* branches fails, reporting that 0{40} is a bad object. After some browsing, I found that I can use this: `git diff-tree --root newrev`. However, this command returns only the files in *the last commit being pushed*, and not all the files in the branch.

Is there a way to get all the names of **all** the files in the branch being pushed if it is a new branch?

Comment: Which kind of [git hook](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html) are you doing this in?

Comment: @StuartM in an update hook on the remote server

Comment: So, specifically, are you using a `post-update` hook?

Comment: No, it is the *update* hook. That is, it is a script in the myproject.git/hooks/ folder, its name is *update*.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for clarifying... proposed an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `git rev-list --first-parent newrev`? It seems to list all the revs between `newrev` and the ref the branch came from. For example, in this repo:

```
$ git log --all --graph --decorate
* commit 03f6357bdcacfc8c8253ccb140f25010810c4433 (HEAD, origin/new_branch, new_branch)
|     Fifth
* commit 291d88908fefa94eab0c9483ad6b8ab5ebca21f6
|     Third
* commit 3ff20b8998d037cd9c9bb1ff53b1887837d9ed8e
|     Second
| * commit e9c2e99de892499d2b6037c8c0913a52dbade4c0 (origin/master, master)
|/      Fourth  
* commit 9574226673ffe2d04ae4e36b4d7976399320e29f
      First
```

`rev-list` gives the following:

```
$ git rev-list --first-parent 03f6357bdcacfc8c8253ccb140f25010810c4433
03f6357bdcacfc8c8253ccb140f25010810c4433
291d88908fefa94eab0c9483ad6b8ab5ebca21f6
3ff20b8998d037cd9c9bb1ff53b1887837d9ed8e
9574226673ffe2d04ae4e36b4d7976399320e29f
```

Which you could limit to just the base ref with `tail -1` (I haven't found a CLI option to do it more elegantly yet):

```
$ git rev-list --first-parent 03f6357bdcacfc8c8253ccb140f25010810c4433 | tail -1
9574226673ffe2d04ae4e36b4d7976399320e29f
```

And from there, you could use your original `git diff` command:

```
$ origrev=`git rev-list --first-parent 03f6357bdcacfc8c8253ccb140f25010810c4433 | tail -1`
$ git diff --name-status --diff-filter=AM $origrev 03f6357bdcacfc8c8253ccb140f25010810c4433
A       bar
```

Comment: It is closer to my goal, but not exactly what I need. Git rev-list --first-parent gives you the *very first* parent, that is, the first commit of the whole repository. But i need the commit, from which this branch was branched off. I'll try looking into the options of rev-list. Thank you.

Comment: I've found "--simplify-by-decoration", that shows only the "interesting" nodes in the tree, where the 0th element would be the point where you branched off. However, it shows that point in the "origin/the_branch" branch, which may be a few commits behind your local branch "the_branch". I wonder, what effects that might have. Again, thank you for your reply.

Comment: Yeah, this gives the first commit ever in the repository. For me, that's *thousands* of commits behind what I (and OP) am loking for